# Problems: Sending and Receiving Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to perform two processes using bean, my problem is that I can not find the way these processes are performed continuously. The first process is to send an object and the second process is the response of the object.

```
@Component
public class Proceso implements InitializingBean{
    private static final String XML_SCHEMA_LOCATION = "/proceso/model/schema/proceso.xsd";
    private Envio envio;
    private Respuesta respuesta;

    public void Proceso_envio(Proceso proceso, OutputStream outputstream) throws JAXBException{
      envio.marshal(proceso, outputstream);}

    public void Proceso_respuesta(InputStream inputstream) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException{
    Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
    return (Proceso_respuesta) obj;}

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception{
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getResource(XML_SCHEMA_LOCATION));
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Envio.class, Respuesta.class);

        this.marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
        this.marshaller.setSchema(schema);

        this.unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        this.unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
     }
```

I imagine that with the code my question becomes clearer.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a [scheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add Syncronized to your methods

i had this trouble many times because the receiver was trying to read something that is not finished

More info in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

when you add this key word to the methods this will wait to the other until it insnt finished

Comment: I understand the problem that teh methods should be invoked **continuously** not **synchronously**

Comment: maybe he meant "synchronously" :)

Comment: Sorry, I have the same question in stackokverflow in Spanish and google translate has not worked very well

Answer (score 1):

thanks maquina,

this is the solution:

```
@Component
public class Proceso implements InitializingBean{
    private static final String XML_SCHEMA_LOCATION = "/proceso/model/schema/proceso.xsd";
    private Envio envio;
    private Respuesta respuesta;

    public synchronized void Proceso_envio(Proceso proceso, OutputStream outputstream) throws JAXBException{
      envio.marshal(proceso, outputstream);}

    public void synchronized Proceso_respuesta(InputStream inputstream) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException{
    Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
    return (Proceso_respuesta) obj;}

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception{
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getResource(XML_SCHEMA_LOCATION));
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Envio.class, Respuesta.class);

        this.marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
        this.marshaller.setSchema(schema);

        this.unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        this.unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
     }
```